# ResponseEntityExceptionHandler not called

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.7.1 and trying to implement Exception handling. Somehow it's not working. Here're the details:

**Controller Advice**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(RoomNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleRoomNotFoundException(RoomNotFoundException e, WebRequest request) {
        
        ErrorMessage errorMessage=new ErrorMessage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.RoomNotFoundException()");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

**RestController Implementation:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WebServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private final ReservationService reservationService;
    @Autowired
    private RoomRepository roomRepository;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WebServiceController []";
    }

    public WebServiceController(ReservationService reservationService) {
        super();
        this.reservationService = reservationService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/jpa/getroomId/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Room getRooms(@PathVariable String id) throws RoomNotFoundException {

        Optional<Room> optionalRoom;
        try {
            optionalRoom = reservationService.getRoomDetail(Integer.parseInt(id));
            if (!optionalRoom.isPresent()) {
                throw new RoomNotFoundException("Room Id is incorrect:" + id);
            }
            return optionalRoom.get();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ErrorMessage Bean class:**

```
public class ErrorMessage {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;

    public ErrorMessage(HttpStatus status, String message) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ErrorMessage() {
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

On Postman when I hit:
I get no return and the Response status code is 200.

On Eclipse server, I get the below output:

```
022-07-28 20:55:41.571  INFO 6893 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8000 (http) with context path ''
2022-07-28 20:55:41.575  INFO 6893 --- [  restartedMain] c.k.j.l.LearningSpringApplication        : Started LearningSpringApplication in 0.891 seconds (JVM running for 1266.472)
2022-07-28 20:55:41.576  INFO 6893 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2022-07-28 20:55:49.292  INFO 6893 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-28 20:55:49.292  INFO 6893 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-28 20:55:49.294  INFO 6893 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Hibernate: select room0_.room_id as room_id1_2_0_, room0_.bed_info as bed_info2_2_0_, room0_.name as name3_2_0_, room0_.room_number as room_num4_2_0_ from room room0_ where room0_.room_id=?
com.khushboo.java.learningspring.exceptions.RoomNotFoundException: Room Id is incorrect:500
    at com.khushboo.java.learningspring.webservice.WebServiceController.getRooms(WebServiceController.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
```

Thanks for taking the time and sharing any helpful insights on why the ExceptionHandler code is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is not get called because here:

```java
   
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

you are swallowing all exceptions, including `RoomNotFoundException`

Comment: That's the catch! I knew I'm missing a bit which is messing up everything! Thanks a ton. So does that mean if I put a catch block, the controller exception handler won't get invoked because the exception is caught? I'm asking because I have also caught NumberFormatException.

Comment: yep. moreover think about refactoring method to smth. like: `public ResponseEntity<?> getRooms(@PathVariable int id)` - in that case you may return `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorMessage)` w/o throwing exception